# ReactJS - Tutorial Comment System > Threaded commenting

Tags: reactjs

Im coming from this https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html

I like my users to reply to any comment, How can I use the same  to add a reply to a comment

I like my children to be added when a reply button below the Comment is clicked, [ Exact functionality like Facebook :) ]
Lets say I have the following JSON

```
    {  
  "comments":[  
    {  
      "id":1,
      "comment_text":"asdasdadasdsadsadadsa",
      "author":"adsfasdasdsad",
      "post_id":1,
      "ancestry":null,
      "archived":false,
      "created_at":"2014-10-16T23:16:44.173Z",
      "updated_at":"2014-10-16T23:16:44.173Z",
      "is_moderated":false,
      "avatar_url":null,
      "slug":null,
      "blog_id":2,
      "children":[  

      ]
    },
    {  
      "id":2,
      "comment_text":"idlsfghlskdhvbsldfhjdslifds\nzf\ndsf\nds\nf\ns\nf\ns\nfds\nfsdjghfsdligjhsepfiguhefdliguhefldiughfeliughnfesg\nf\nsg\ns\ng\ns\ndf\nsd\nf\nsdgsofughlefidughls;uhgsuhg.vskjfhglsiuhg.sfv",
      "author":"asdsdasdad",
      "post_id":1,
      "ancestry":null,
      "archived":false,
      "created_at":"2014-10-16T23:17:02.270Z",
      "updated_at":"2014-10-16T23:17:02.270Z",
      "is_moderated":false,
      "avatar_url":null,
      "slug":null,
      "blog_id":2,
      "children":[  
        {  
          "id":3,
          "comment_text":"fdsfdsfdsfsdfsfsdf",
          "author":"sdfdsfdsfdsfds",
          "post_id":1,
          "ancestry":"2",
          "archived":false,
          "created_at":"2014-11-28T17:39:47.059Z",
          "updated_at":"2014-11-28T17:39:47.059Z",
          "is_moderated":false,
          "avatar_url":null,
          "slug":null,
          "blog_id":2,
          "children":[  
            {  
              "id":4,
              "comment_text":"fdsfdsfdsdsfdsfds",
              "author":"sdfsdfdsfsdfdsfds",
              "post_id":1,
              "ancestry":"2/3",
              "archived":false,
              "created_at":"2014-11-28T17:39:53.049Z",
              "updated_at":"2014-11-28T17:39:53.049Z",
              "is_moderated":false,
              "avatar_url":null,
              "slug":null,
              "blog_id":2,
              "children":[  
                {  
                  "id":5,
                  "comment_text":"sdfdsfdsfdsfdssdfsdfdsfdsfdsfds",
                  "author":"sdfsdfdsfdsfdsf",
                  "post_id":1,
                  "ancestry":"2/3/4",
                  "archived":false,
                  "created_at":"2014-11-28T17:40:02.032Z",
                  "updated_at":"2014-11-28T17:40:02.032Z",
                  "is_moderated":false,
                  "avatar_url":null,
                  "slug":null,
                  "blog_id":2,
                  "children":[  

                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please add your code and explain what isn't working. As written, your question seems to ask for someone to code the entire solution.

Comment: Please see this Fiddle for a working demo, Lets move on from here to EDIT http://jsfiddle.net/lordizuriel/AdJw3/

Comment: Was it helpful @WiredPrairie ?

Comment: What's the problem though?

Comment: The Problem is my lack of knowledge in ReactJS

Comment: There are hundreds of great resources about ReactJS available. Your question still reads like a coding request and not a specific problem you've encountered.